# Get data from join

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm struggling for a while here. I need to display a table with some data. I've to get this data from different entities. I can't to get one value correctly as my join seems to break to correct data.

He is my Repository function :

```
    $qb->select('j AS jou')
        ->innerJoin('j.playeds', 'p')
        ->addSelect('SUM(p.points) AS sumpoints')
        ->addSelect('SUM(p.max) AS summax')
        ->addSelect('COUNT(p.partie) as sumparties')
        ->addSelect('SUM(CASE WHEN p.position = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sumwins')
        ->groupBy('j.id')
        ->orderBy('sumpoints', 'DESC')
        ->innerJoin('j.disputeds','d')
        ->addSelect('COUNT(d.id) AS nbDisputeds')
        ->addGroupBy('d.id');
```

At this point, everything works except this :

```
->addSelect('COUNT(d.id) AS nbDisputeds')
```

The data displayed is wrong probably because of my groupBy.
It should give me the number of "disputeds" occurences I have for each "j" but the result isn't correct.

Any help is welcome :)

Edit2: I tried from another repository but I get the same result, the problem is simply reported on other attributes :

```
    $qb->select('d')
        ->innerJoin('d.joueur', 'j')
        ->addSelect('j.nom, j.prenom')
        ->addSelect('SUM(d.points) AS sumpoints')
        ->addSelect('COUNT(d) as sumparties')
        ->addSelect('SUM(CASE WHEN d.position = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sumwins')
        ->GroupBy('d.joueur')
        ->leftJoin('j.playeds','p')
        ->addSelect('SUM(p.max) AS summax')
        ->addGroupBy('j.id')
        ->addGroupBy('p.partie');
```

In this case, I get correct values for sumpoints, sumparties, sumwins but summax gives me an incoherent value. That probably comes from a "bad" groupBy somewhere, i don't know..

Edit3 :

Works :

```
SELECT SUM(d0_.points) AS points, d0_.position AS position, j1_.nom AS nom, j1_.prenom AS prenom FROM disputed d0_ INNER JOIN joueur j1_ ON d0_.joueur_id = j1_.id GROUP BY d0_.joueur_id
```

But I don't have "max" value. Table "played" also is not joined

Doesn't Work :

```
SELECT SUM(d0_.points) AS points, j1_.nom AS nom, j1_.prenom AS prenom, SUM(p2_.max) AS maxs FROM disputed d0_ INNER JOIN joueur j1_ ON d0_.joueur_id = j1_.id INNER JOIN played p2_ ON j1_.id = p2_.joueur_id GROUP BY p2_.joueur_id
```

Table "played" is joined, "points" and "maxs" are not correct values

Database schema :

[image]

Entities :

Joueur Entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\JoueurRepository")
 */
class Joueur
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $prenom;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Disputed", mappedBy="joueur", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $disputeds;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Played", mappedBy="joueur")
     */
    private $playeds;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->disputeds = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->playeds = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrenom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->prenom;
    }

    public function setPrenom(string $prenom): self
    {
        $this->prenom = $prenom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Disputed[]
     */
    public function getDisputeds(): Collection
    {
        return $this->disputeds;
    }

    public function addDisputed(Disputed $disputed): self
    {
        if (!$this->disputeds->contains($disputed)) {
            $this->disputeds[] = $disputed;
            $disputed->setJoueur($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeDisputed(Disputed $disputed): self
    {
        if ($this->disputeds->contains($disputed)) {
            $this->disputeds->removeElement($disputed);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($disputed->getJoueur() === $this) {
                $disputed->setJoueur(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
{
    $string = $this->getPrenom().' '.$this->getNom();
    return $string;
}

    /**
     * @return Collection|Played[]
     */
    public function getPlayeds(): Collection
    {
        return $this->playeds;
    }

    public function addPlayed(Played $played): self
    {
        if (!$this->playeds->contains($played)) {
            $this->playeds[] = $played;
            $played->setJoueur($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removePlayed(Played $played): self
    {
        if ($this->playeds->contains($played)) {
            $this->playeds->removeElement($played);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($played->getJoueur() === $this) {
                $played->setJoueur(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Disputed Entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\DisputedRepository")
 */
class Disputed
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $points;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $position;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Joueur", inversedBy="disputeds")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $joueur;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Tournoi", inversedBy="disputeds")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $tournament;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getPoints(): ?int
    {
        return $this->points;
    }

    public function setPoints(int $points): self
    {
        $this->points = $points;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPosition(): ?int
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    public function setPosition(int $position): self
    {
        $this->position = $position;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getJoueur(): ?Joueur
    {
        return $this->joueur;
    }

    public function setJoueur(?Joueur $joueur): self
    {
        $this->joueur = $joueur;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTournament(): ?Tournoi
    {
        return $this->tournament;
    }

    public function setTournament(?Tournoi $tournament): self
    {
        $this->tournament = $tournament;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Tournoi Entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TournoiRepository")
 */
class Tournoi
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Disputed", mappedBy="tournament")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"points" = "DESC"})
     */
    private $disputeds;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Partie", mappedBy="tournoi")
     */
    private $Parties;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $nbPlayers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->disputeds = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->parties = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->Parties = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    public function setDate(\DateTimeInterface $date): self
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Disputed[]
     */
    public function getDisputeds(): Collection
    {
        return $this->disputeds;
    }

    public function addDisputed(Disputed $disputed): self
    {
        if (!$this->disputeds->contains($disputed)) {
            $this->disputeds[] = $disputed;
            $disputed->setTournament($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeDisputed(Disputed $disputed): self
    {
        if ($this->disputeds->contains($disputed)) {
            $this->disputeds->removeElement($disputed);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($disputed->getTournament() === $this) {
                $disputed->setTournament(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Partie[]
     */
    public function getParties(): Collection
    {
        return $this->parties;
    }

    public function addPartie(Partie $partie): self
    {
        if (!$this->parties->contains($partie)) {
            $this->parties[] = $partie;
            $partie->setTournoi($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removePartie(Partie $partie): self
    {
        if ($this->parties->contains($partie)) {
            $this->parties->removeElement($partie);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($partie->getTournoi() === $this) {
                $partie->setTournoi(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNbPlayers(): ?int
    {
        return $this->nbPlayers;
    }

    public function setNbPlayers(?int $nbPlayers): self
    {
        $this->nbPlayers = $nbPlayers;

        return $this;
    }

    public function addParty(Partie $party): self
    {
        if (!$this->Parties->contains($party)) {
            $this->Parties[] = $party;
            $party->setTournoi($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeParty(Partie $party): self
    {
        if ($this->Parties->contains($party)) {
            $this->Parties->removeElement($party);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($party->getTournoi() === $this) {
                $party->setTournoi(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Comment: what do you expect to have as result ?

Comment: The amount of tournaments played by each "joueur".

Comment: looking for a result like :
player 1 ==> 4 
player2 ==> 5

Comment: can you show table schema of  player , match and tournament ?

Comment: @Mohammed, sure, I edited my post with the 3 entities

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI any idea ?

Comment: Why are you using the last 2 group by ?
In my experience when trying to get a query big like this, i start small and continue growing. Maybe separate the first query and then make the second one. Can you do that in separate queries and then join them with an array if its giving you much pain.

Comment: @simon that's what gave me the best result until now. If I add two queries in an array, how I'm sure that I'll get the correct value for each "joueur" ? I mean results won't be ordered the same way for each query.

Comment: as soon as I join tables "played" and "disputed" to "joueur", that's where it breaks